# How to make Hyperlink underline color same as foreground Text color

Tags: wpf

I would like to have a WPF hyperlink style where the underline is the same color as the text (foreground), where the text foreground color can be overridden with local property and both text and underline colors change to the specified value.

Default styling works (is that because the underline inherits the Pen brush from the Text??), but I need to have my custom style which has different underline thickness. To specify thickness I believe I need to declare its a Pen and its Brush and I don't know how to declare the Brush such that it refers to / inherits from the Style's foreground. Any suggestions please?

```xml
<Style TargetType="Hyperlink">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGrey" />
    <Setter Property="TextDecorations">
        <Setter.Value>
            <TextDecorationCollection>
                <TextDecoration Location="Underline" PenOffset="2">
                    <TextDecoration.Pen>
                        <Pen Brush="[Hyperlink's Foreground of DarkGray]" Thickness="2" />
                    </TextDecoration.Pen>
                </TextDecoration>
            </TextDecorationCollection>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray" />
            <Setter Property="TextDecorations">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <TextDecorationCollection>
                        <TextDecoration Location="Underline" PenOffset="2">
                            <TextDecoration.Pen>
                                <Pen Brush="[Hyperlink's MouseOver Foreground color of Gray]" Thickness="3" />
                            </TextDecoration.Pen>
                        </TextDecoration>
                    </TextDecorationCollection>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Also I can't override the IsMouseOver Trigger Foreground with a local property - am I right that it is due to the limitation of WPF's style triggers and I'm forced to define a new style replacing all trigger(s) just to change that one MouseOver color?

Answer (score 0):

You would simply bind the Pen's Brush to the Foreground of the Hyperlink:

```
<Pen Brush="{Binding Foreground,
             RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Hyperlink}}" ... />
```

Comment: Gives a XAML Binding error: Cannot find source: RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Documents.Hyperlink', AncestorLevel='1'.

Comment: Works fine for me. In a Hyperlink Style as in your question of course.

Comment: The WPF debugging toolbar shows a red circle with white cross and when clicked it takes you to the VS 2022 XAML Binding Failures window which shows the above error. Despite the error, the underline color matches the foreground. I had tried your solution previously and raised this question because of this error. I was told the reason for the error is because the TextDecoration is a Animatable/Freezable and not part of the visual tree and that's why the FindAncestor fails. But it doesn't explain how the color actually works.

Comment: If it helps, I have your Hyperlink Style in `<Window.Resources>` in the MainWindow of a .NET Framework 4.8 WPF application in VS 2019.

Comment: Style was in Windows.Resources, but I tried with VS 2019 and Framework 4.8 with your suggested binding and I still get the binding error